# Natural scrolling for both touchpad and wireless mouse

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, mouse-scroll

I'd like to set the scroll wheel of my wireless mouse to follow the "natural" scrolling, i.e.: scroll up when rolling the wheel up and down when the wheel rolls down, so it follows the same setting than my laptop's touchpad.

On Ubuntu 16.04 the Natural scrolling option is available for the touchpad only. When it is disabled like in the screenshot below, both the touchpad and mouse scroll the classic Windows way, when I check it the touchpad scrolls like I want, the natural way made popular by Apple but the mouse still scrolls in classic mode. How to get both working as desired?

[image: Mouse and Touchpad settings]